# Duda sobre la forma de mostrar un formulario

Tags: python, django, html, css

Buenas, tardes tengo un formulario creado de la siguiente forma:

(en forms)

```
RESULTADO_P = (
    ('a', 'a'),
    ('b', 'b'),
    ('c', 'c'),
    ('?', '?'),
    )


class formulario(forms.Form):
   r1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESULTADO_P, initial='?')
```

(en index)

```
{{form.r1}}
```

y se me muestra de la siguiente forma :

[image: formulario]

Mi pregunta es como podría conseguir que esas opciones se visualizaran en 4 checkbox y que el usuario eligiera uno de ellos.

Gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces debes usar el campo `MultipleChoiceField` en el modelo. En el formulario se usa el *widget* `SelectMultiple` que tiene la misma sintaxis.

La referencia en la documentación oficial para el campo [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) y para [SelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple).

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ahora la duda es como conseguir que el resultado al mostrar dichas opciones sea horizontal y no vertical.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta o crea una nueva para esta otra duda.

Comment: @user5872256 Bienvenido a StackOverflow si alguna de las respuesta ayudo a la solucion a tu problema puede barajar la posibilidad de aceptarla como solucion o votarla +1 de esa manera ayudara a otros puede leer este link -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr, si quieres mostrar varios checkbox y que puedan escoger solo una opción, entonces lo que necesitas es cambiar el Widget a [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) para usar radio buttons y que el usuario solo pueda escoger una sola opción:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets

class formulario(forms.Form):
    r1 = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=RESULTADO_P, 
        widget=widgets.RadioSelect
    )
```

Si quieres usar selección múltiple, tendrías que usar lo que indica @toledano y cambiar a `MultipleChoiceField`:

```
from django import forms

class formulario(forms.Form):
    r1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=RESULTADO_P, 
        initial='?'
    )
```

No se si las opciones que has creado sean las adecuadas, si vas a cambiar a selección múltiple tal vez ya no necesites la opción `?`:

```
RESULTADO_P = (
    ('a', 'a'),
    ('b', 'b'),
    ('c', 'c'),
)

class formulario(forms.Form):
    r1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RESULTADO_P)
```

Aún asi es posible seguir usando el parámetro `initial` en tu formulario. por ejemplo, si quieres que inicialmente se seleccionen las opciones `a` y `c`, puedes pasarle una lista como parámetro:

```
class formulario(forms.Form):
    r1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RESULTADO_P, initial=['a', 'c'])
```

Ahora, para cambiar la selección a checkbox, solo tienes que modificar el Widget que usas para ese campo y usar [`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple):

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets

class formulario(forms.Form):
    r1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=RESULTADO_P, 
        widget=widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

Por otro lado, sería bueno que expliques lo que quieres lograr al decir que el resultado se muestre en **forma horizontal**. Se me ocurre que lo puedes conseguir usando CSS.